# nextJS .next cache error: "Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: caching, next.js, vercel

I've been working on my nextjs project when these types of cache errors started appearing randomly with no obvious pattern. There's two types of errors, the first type that doesn't really affect the way I test it with localhost, and the second type which displays "404: Client Error Occurred" in the browser requiring me to delete the `.next` folder and `npm run dev` again.

```
 ✓ Compiled /_error in 222ms (1039 modules)
 ✓ Compiled in 365ms (992 modules)
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/6.pack.gz'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/6.pack.gz'
}
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/6.pack.gz'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/6.pack.gz'
}
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/6.pack.gz'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/6.pack.gz'
}
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/6.pack.gz'
```

This is an example of cache error that would display "404: Client Error Occurred" in the browser requiring me to delete the `.next` folder and `npm run dev` again

```
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/server/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js'
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Resolving '../../../../../../../.next/server/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]' in /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader for build dependencies doesn't lead to expected result '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/server/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js', but to 'Error: Can't resolve '../../../../../../../.next/server/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth]' in '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader'' instead. Resolving dependencies are ignored for this path.
<w>  at resolve commonjs file ../../../../../../../.next/server/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth] (expected /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/.next/server/pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js)
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader/node-module-loader.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader/node-module-loader.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader/route-module-loader.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader/route-module-loader.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/export/routes/app-route.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/export/routes/app-route.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/export/worker.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/worker.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-route-loader/index.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-route-loader/index.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-runner/LoaderRunner.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/loader-runner/LoaderRunner.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/webpack.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/webpack.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/define-env-plugin.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/plugins/define-env-plugin.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/swc/index.js
<w>  at file dependencies /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
<w>  at file /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
<w>  at resolve commonjs /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-webapp/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-swc-loader.js
```